# How to check if order confirmation and shipment emails were sent out successfully?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, email, shipment

How to check if order confirmation and shipment emails were sent out successfully? Any way to track from the admin or through log file?

The "Order" and "Order Comments" setting in the System->Configuration->Sale Emails are Enabled.

Answer (score 1):

If you have same problems when you send your letter, you can see it in a file `exception.log`   because in   `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Queue.php`  it is provided (you can see   `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue::send()`  at the end of method). But if *exception* doesn’t appear, it doesn’t means that recipient got your letter. It means that letter was sent to the mail service (successful execution of the function `mail()` in PHP).

Comment: I think in backend sales order page, in the comment history section , if the Customer Not Notified" means no mail sent and "Customer Notified" means mail sent what you think ?

Comment: Yes, but it is only flag for options send or not send the letter. It doesn’t mean that the user got letter. But if you don’t see exception in your exception.log, it is likely that letter came

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Mage::log()

store response you get after calling mail function and then use if condition.

```
if($response){
    Mage::log('Mail Sent Successfully');
}else{
    Mage::log('Error Sending in Mail');
}
```

Please don't add any code in your core magento files because it is not a good practice

**Update**

You can utilize magento notification

```
Mage::getSingleton(‘core/session’)->addNotice(‘Notice message’);
```

For More Details you can go thorough this link

http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-frontend/utilizing-magento-notification-system/

Comment: any way to check from the magento backend ?

Comment: as per my knowledge i am not sure that by default there is a way to do it but you can utilize magento notification

Mage::getSingleton(‘core/session’)->addNotice(‘Notice message’);

For More Details you can go thorough this link
http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-frontend/utilizing-magento-notification-system/

For your suitability i am updating my answer too with same code

Comment: I think in backend sales order page, in the comment history section , if the Customer Not Notified" means no mail sent and "Customer Notified" means mail sent
what you think ?

Comment: programmatically i know if it helped you, please up vote my answer

Answer (score 0):

Go to particular order there is  **(the order confirmation email was sent)**

Open shipment just after title

As an example

```
Shipment #100000003 | 23/03/2016 15.47.25 (the shipment email was sent)
```

If email sent -> **(the shipment email was sent)**

If email not sent -> **(the shipment email is not sent)**

Comment: but what about the order ?

Comment: In particular order edit page  there is same notification like Order # 100000053 (the order confirmation email was sent)